# how to place dots on coordinate grid with react-konva?

Tags: reactjs, react-konva

I use React for frontend and I've created grid with react-konva:

```js
import { Stage, Layer, Circle, Group, Line } from 'react-konva';
import { bushes } from '../../bushes';
const WIDTH = 700;
const HEIGHT = 700;
const gridSize = 100;
const renderGrid = () => {
    const linesA = [];
    const linesB = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= WIDTH / gridSize; i++) {
        linesA.push(
          <Line
            strokeWidth={1}
            stroke={"black"}
            opacity={0.3}
            points={[i * gridSize, 0, i * gridSize, WIDTH]}
          />
        );
      
        linesB.push(
          <Line
            strokeWidth={1}
            stroke={"black"}
            opacity={0.3}
            points={[0, i * gridSize, WIDTH, i * gridSize]}
          />
        );
      }
      return {
        linesA,
        linesB
      }
}

const renderPoints = () => {
    const points = [];
    const xSteps = Math.round(WIDTH / gridSize);
    const ySteps = Math.round(HEIGHT / gridSize);
  
    for (let i = 0; i <= xSteps; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j <= ySteps; j++) {
        const x = i * gridSize;
        const y = j * gridSize;
  
        points.push(
          <Group key={`${i}-${j}`}>
            <Circle
             x={x}
             y={y}
             fill="black"
             width={19}
             height={19}
             opacity={0.3}
            />
          </Group>
        );
      }
    }
  
    return points;
  };
  


const Grid = () => {
  return (
    <Stage
     width={window.innerWidth}
     height={window.innerHeight}
    >
        <Layer>
            {renderGrid().linesA}
            {renderGrid().linesB}
           {renderPoints()}
        </Layer>
    </Stage>
  )
};
export default Grid;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-wave-g3gpyh?file=/src/components/Grid/Grid.jsx). Basically, it looks like it was intended.
But in my code i draw grid with mock points and real points come from the backend, in the form of an array that I need to go through and render the points by coordinates. Dots data has such structure:

```js
const points = [
    {
        id: 0,
        refPoint: 34,
        pos: [0,0]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        refPoint: 40,
        pos: [0,1]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        refPoint: 5,
        pos: [0,2]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        refPoint: 99,
        pos: [0,3]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        refPoint: 1,
        pos: [0,4]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        refPoint: 20,
        pos: [0,5]
    },
]
```

The field pos is responsible for the coordinates, 1-st is x, 2-nd - y. The grid should be drawn down, based on this data, 6 cells down should be obtained (1 column).

Issue:
I need to fill the grid with dots from an array but they are all either diagonally left to right down or all at the same top point.

Maybe I didn’t start drawing the grid correctly, I understand the canvas only on the 2nd day and I don’t quite understand how to make such a grid correctly, first it will render the cells in one layer, then in another point.I will be very grateful for ideas and solutions!